# Cloudant AuthCookie may not be null

Tags: java, maven, cloudant

I am currently trying to add entries into Cloudant using this link:
https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant#installation-and-usage

Below is my code

```
package sample;

import java.util.List;

import com.cloudant.client.api.CloudantClient;

public class Cloudant {
    public static void main (String[] args){

    String password = System.getProperty("gffgasdas");
    CloudantClient client = new CloudantClient("wiz.cloudant.com",password);



    System.out.println("Connected to Cloudant");
    System.out.println("Server Version: " + client.serverVersion());

    List<String> databases = client.getAllDbs();
    System.out.println("All my databases : ");
    for ( String db : databases ) {
        System.out.println(db);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AuthCookie may not be null.
    at org.lightcouch.internal.CouchDbUtil.assertNotEmpty(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudant.client.api.CloudantClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sample.Cloudant.main(Cloudant.java:11)
```

I have all the necessary important imports. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: I've fixed up the formatting of your question. To display blocks of code nicely just select the whole code segment and use the 'Code' button on the editor. Exceptions also look quite nice in this format, the `small code block` tags look bad on large blocks but are good for `highlighting` key words.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're using the right constructor. It looks like you need to use the three-argument constructor `CloudantClient(cloudantAccountName, username, password)`.

Your line:

`CloudantClient client = new CloudantClient("wiz.cloudant.com",password);`

Needs to be:

`CloudantClient client = new CloudantClient("wiz", "wiz", password);`

The two-argument version assumes you are passing a cookie rather than a password.